# WebGL: Pass texture from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: glsl, webgl

Is it possible to pass a texture from a vertex to a fragment shader in WebGL? If so, how can one achieve this behavior?

I tried to pass a Sampler2D to the frag shader and got an error:

> sampler2Ds must be uniform

I'd be grateful for any help others can offer on this question!

Comment: Please show as much of your vs and fs source code as possible to help us help you

Comment: @DacreDenny are you saying it's possible to pass a texture from a vertex shader to a frag shader? I didn't post code because the error seems to assert a sampler2D must be a uniform, rather than a varying. Anyway I'll update the question...

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you pass a texture from the vertex shader to the fragment shader? Just declare the same sampler in both shader?

vertex shader

```
...
uniform sampler2D foo;
....
```

fragment shader

```
...
uniform sampler2D foo;
...
```

Otherwise the answer is no, you can't pass a texture between shaders. You can pass some value to select sampler results

vertex shader

```
varying float textureSelector;
...
textureSelector = ???
```

fragment shader

```
vec4 color1 = texture2D(foo, ...);
vec4 color2 = texture2D(bar, ...);
vec4 color = mix(color1, color2, textureSelector);
```

Note: Updated based on comments from Nicol, According to the spec textures break if used in inside conditional code. From [the spec, Appendix A.6](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf)

> ## Texture Accesses
>
> Accessing mip-mapped textures within the body of a non-uniform conditional block gives an undefined value. A non-uniform conditional block is a block whose execution cannot be determined at compile time

In other words code like this might not work

```
varying float textureSelector;
uniform sampler2D foo;
uniform sampler2D bar;

...

if (textureSelector > ???) {
  ... use foo ...
} else {
  ... use bar ...
}
```

so I guess it's best to sample all the textures in a non-conditional part of your shader and then either use math like `mix` above or use conditionals after you've gotten the values out of the textures. An example of accessing N textures but choosing only 1.

```
#define NUM_TEXTURES 6
uniform sampler2D u_textures[NUM_TEXTURES];
varying float textureSelector;  // 0 to NUM_TEXTURES - 1
void main() {
  vec4 color = vec4(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXTURES; ++i) {
    float id = float(i);
    float mult = step(id - .5, textureSelector) * step(textureSelector, id + .5);
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_textures[i], someTexCoord);
    color = mix(color, texColor, mult); 
  }
  ... use color ...
}
```

Of course for most use cases you should probably be using a texture atlas and using texture coordinates to select parts of it. The normal reasons to use multiple textures are things like normal maps, opacity maps, reflectivity maps, ambient occlusion, lighting and or smooth mixes like dirt/grass/snow in which cases you wouldn't need conditionals. To re-iterate, it's not common to select from multiple textures in a shader.

Comment: thanks I thought that was the case. Do you know if there exists a list of all possible varying data types? The use case was avoiding a large texture lookup tree in the fragment shader (I have multiple textures, and if I could find the appropriate one for a fragment in the vertex shader I thought that would be optimal). Can you say more about what you mean when you say "You can pass some value to select shaders" -- can I define one frag shader for each texture then just variabilize the fragment shader used for a given point?

Comment: "*if (textureSelector > ???)*" There are a ton of caveats that come along with doing that. Does WebGL support the `dFdx/y` functions and `textureGrad`? If not, then such a selector will introduce problems. At least, if the actual texture fetch is done in the condition. If you do both fetches before and ignore one of the in the condition, that would work.

Comment: There's a list of possible varyings in the [WebGL Reference Sheet](https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf) and of course [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) which the reference sheet shows the sections in the spec for each topic.

Comment: Thanks @gman. I'm casting my texture index to an int then using that to perform the lookup -- does that resolve the troubles you mentioned, NicolBolas?

Comment: I know of no non-obvious issues with selecting textures based on varyings. Of course they are varyings so they **vary**. Casting to int won't stop them from varying. Passing the same value for every vertex of a triangle will. I really depends on what you want to do with them. Of course you can also mix. GLSL is just a programming language. It's up to you to write the correct math given the inputs.

Comment: @gman: "*I know of no non-obvious issues with selecting textures based on varyings.*" Obvious is of course in the eye of the behilder. WebGL 1.0 is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, which declares that texture accesses in non-uniform control flow (such as a condition based on a varying) will not have implicit derivatives. That can break your texturing. This is "obvious" to myself only because I'm very experienced with these errors.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'd be curious to know more details. I see it's in the spec (Appendix A.6) but I'm curious what varyings have to do with textures. I can sample a texture based on anything. `dFdx` is an attribute of a varying and *should* have absolutely nothing to with textures. To put it another way `vec4 c = texture2D(someTex, anythingWhatSoEverGoesHere)` so it's interesting that this would have an influence on varyings suddenly breaking. Textures breaking non-uniform code is in the spec. Are there any modern GPUs to show this issue off? Made a sample here:http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/bkpd5r9z/

Comment: @gman: "*I'm curious what varyings have to do with textures*" Varyings in a conditional can create non-uniform control flow. And non-uniform control flow can cause textures to not have accurate implicit derivatives. "*Are there any modern GPUs to show this issue off?*" I don't know that it matters; undefined behavior is undefined behavior. I would imagine that no modern NVIDIA hardware exhibits this problem. But people shouldn't *rely* on that, even only on NVIDIA platforms. Stick to the spec, and you can get well-defined behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Specs get out of date. If some ES 2.0 GPU in 2007 had this issue but 99% of GPUs actually in use in 2018 don't then it's a non issue. That's why I'm asking. Specs are also often wrong. As someone that's written an OpenGL ES driver I've filed several bugs against the specs where they've been wrong. WebGL also often makes stronger guarantees then ES. If this is a case where no GPUs in general use exhibit this issue it's possible WebGL would add support as a requirement and add tests to verify. We've done this for other parts of the spec.

Comment: @gman: Considering that *desktop* GLSL 4.60 also has this restriction, as well as SPIR-V (though SPIR-V is a bit more fine-grained, as uniformity only has to be within the "derivative group"), I rather suspect not. I highly doubt all of these specifications missed something. As for whether a limitation of the spec should be ignored on the basis of what modern GPUs do, that's for each person to decide for themselves. At the very least, if you're going to tell someone to violate the specification, let them know so that they can make their own choice.

Comment: @gman: BTW, feel free to file a bug report on it. If you do, please mention that GLSL is more restrictive than the SPIR-V equivalent, so even if they don't remove the restriction, they can at least minimize it.